# Using perf, how to record for all -e events gcc’s -fauto-profile supports?

Tags: linux, gcc, profiling, profiler, perf

Simple question but I couldn’t find the answer. Given the very long list of possible options with suboptions not included :

```
  branch-instructions OR branches                    [Hardware event]
  branch-misses                                      [Hardware event]
  bus-cycles                                         [Hardware event]
  cache-misses                                       [Hardware event]
  cache-references                                   [Hardware event]
  cpu-cycles OR cycles                               [Hardware event]
  instructions                                       [Hardware event]
  ref-cycles                                         [Hardware event]
  alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
  bpf-output                                         [Software event]
  context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
  cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
  cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
  dummy                                              [Software event]
  emulation-faults                                   [Software event]
  major-faults                                       [Software event]
  minor-faults                                       [Software event]
  page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
  task-clock                                         [Software event]
  duration_time                                      [Tool event]
  user_time                                          [Tool event]
  system_time                                        [Tool event]
  L1-dcache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-loads                                    [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-stores                                   [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-load-misses                                    [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-loads                                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-store-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-stores                                         [Hardware cache event]
  branch-load-misses                                 [Hardware cache event]
  branch-loads                                       [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  node-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  node-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  branch-instructions OR cpu/branch-instructions/    [Kernel PMU event]
  branch-misses OR cpu/branch-misses/                [Kernel PMU event]
  bus-cycles OR cpu/bus-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  cache-misses OR cpu/cache-misses/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  cache-references OR cpu/cache-references/          [Kernel PMU event]
  cpu-cycles OR cpu/cpu-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  instructions OR cpu/instructions/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  mem-loads OR cpu/mem-loads/                        [Kernel PMU event]
  mem-stores OR cpu/mem-stores/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  ref-cycles OR cpu/ref-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-fetch-bubbles OR cpu/topdown-fetch-bubbles/ [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-recovery-bubbles OR cpu/topdown-recovery-bubbles/ [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-slots-issued OR cpu/topdown-slots-issued/  [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-slots-retired OR cpu/topdown-slots-retired/ [Kernel PMU event]
  topdown-total-slots OR cpu/topdown-total-slots/    [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_core/c3-residency/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_core/c6-residency/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_core/c7-residency/                          [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c2-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c3-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c6-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  cstate_pkg/c7-residency/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  intel_bts//                                        [Kernel PMU event]
  intel_pt//                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/aperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/cpu_thermal_margin/                            [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/mperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/pperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/smi/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/tsc/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  power/energy-pkg/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
  power/energy-ram/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_in_port0/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_in_port1/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_in_port2/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_in_port3/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_out_port0/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_out_port1/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_out_port2/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/bw_out_port3/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/ioclk/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_in_port0/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_in_port1/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_in_port2/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_in_port3/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_out_port0/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_out_port1/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_out_port2/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_0/util_out_port3/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_in_port0/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_in_port1/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_in_port2/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_in_port3/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_out_port0/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_out_port1/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_out_port2/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/bw_out_port3/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/ioclk/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_in_port0/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_in_port1/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_in_port2/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_in_port3/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_out_port0/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_out_port1/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_out_port2/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_1/util_out_port3/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_in_port0/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_in_port1/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_in_port2/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_in_port3/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_out_port0/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_out_port1/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_out_port2/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/bw_out_port3/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/ioclk/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_in_port0/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_in_port1/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_in_port2/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_in_port3/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_out_port0/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_out_port1/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_out_port2/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_2/util_out_port3/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_in_port0/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_in_port1/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_in_port2/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_in_port3/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_out_port0/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_out_port1/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_out_port2/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/bw_out_port3/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/ioclk/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_in_port0/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_in_port1/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_in_port2/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_in_port3/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_out_port0/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_out_port1/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_out_port2/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_3/util_out_port3/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_in_port0/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_in_port1/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_in_port2/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_in_port3/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_out_port0/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_out_port1/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_out_port2/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/bw_out_port3/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/ioclk/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_in_port0/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_in_port1/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_in_port2/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_in_port3/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_out_port0/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_out_port1/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_out_port2/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_4/util_out_port3/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_in_port0/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_in_port1/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_in_port2/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_in_port3/             [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_out_port0/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_out_port1/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_out_port2/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/bw_out_port3/            [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/ioclk/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_in_port0/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_in_port1/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_in_port2/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_in_port3/           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_out_port0/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_out_port1/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_out_port2/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_iio_free_running_5/util_out_port3/          [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_0/cas_count_read/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_0/cas_count_write/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_0/clockticks/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_1/cas_count_read/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_1/cas_count_write/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_1/clockticks/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_2/cas_count_read/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_2/cas_count_write/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_2/clockticks/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_3/cas_count_read/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_3/cas_count_write/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_3/clockticks/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_4/cas_count_read/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_4/cas_count_write/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_4/clockticks/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_5/cas_count_read/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_5/cas_count_write/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  uncore_imc_5/clockticks/                           [Kernel PMU event]
```

how to enable all of them for `-fauto-profile` in gcc ? Or rather, what’s the `-e` option which means all of them ?

Comment: You normally don't want to do that because only 4 or 8 hardware events (PMU) can be active at one on the same core (depending on the CPU model and whether hyperthreading is enabled), so enabling boatloads of events would get `perf` to multiplex them in groups.  E.g. Skylake has 8 programmable counters per physical core, partitioned to 4 per logical core unless hyperthreading is fully disabled at boot.  Plus it has fixed counters for the `cycles` and `instructions` events, so if perf was smarter, it wouldn't have to multiplex those.

Comment: But anyway, having a counter only active for 1/16th of the run time (for example) might happen to miss phases of the program where those things happened.  If you look at `perf stat -ddd` output, you'll see multiplexing percentages.  So anyway, if you can re-run your profile-generate test-run with the same input multiple times, that would be one way to record sets of events, if that can append to a perf.data file instead of replacing.

Comment: @PeterCordes **so at least it should be possible to enable all software based events**. Then, in my case I have 32 logical Intel cores. I want to enable all the option supported by `-fauto-profile` for gcc.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible to let perf multiplex a boatload of events, should just take some text processing to parse `perf list` output into a comma-separated list for a `-e` arg.  The number of logical cores in the system is basically irrelevant, unless you want to profile separate small batches on separate cores in parallel.  If you're recording 4 events for a run of the program, those 4 events need to be programmed into the HW PMU on every logical cores your process runs threads on.

Comment: @PeterCordes so there are no option which at least means all software events ? And which options are relevant for `-fauto-profile`?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used GCC's auto-profile, just `-fprofile-generate` / `-fprofile-use` which adds software instrumentation.  And I don't know of an option to enable all events, otherwise I'd have posted my earlier comments as part of an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes as the gcc’s advanced documentation state, the problem is `-fprofile-generate` works by inserting extra code which results in modifying profile data. Isn’t there a way to make `perf list` outputting more parsable results so a script can build the list ?

Comment: *which results in modifying profile data* - yes of course, you don't use `perf record` on an instrumented build.  As for perf list, `perf list --no-desc` has pretty simple `event [type]` output until you get to the last two lines (for numeric event specifiers), and then the `Metric Groups:` part, so just end parsing there.

Comment: @PeterCordes no, with perf, the build doesn’t need to be instrumented for collecting events, hence why the gcc’s documentation states AutoFdo is better. I recognize a proper answer would be the command line.

Comment: What do you mean "no"?  I know how both ways of doing profile-guided optimization work (and that they're separate and shouldn't be mixed), I just haven't used autoFdo myself.  I guess they determine branch likelihood by looking at counts for `instructions` within basic blocks, or something, instead of instrumenting branches.  But I hadn't realized GCC's docs recommended AutoFdo as being "better", so thanks for that.

Comment: @PeterCordes `AutoFdo` just converts the perf generated files into a gcov like format. Everything is done by `perf record` mostly in hardware.